# Writing a string to the last line in a file, Python

Tags: python, string, file, io

I'm attempting to make a function that writes a string to the last line in a file. However, what I currently have (below) only writes to the first line. So if I call the function more than once, it simply overwrites the first line. I'd like it to instead write the string to a new line; how would I go about this?

Snippet :

```
def write (self, string) :
    # self.Dir is a txt file
    self.File = file(self.Dir, 'w')
    self.File.write(string)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Open the file in append mode (`'a'` instead of `'w'`). Opening in `'w'` mode truncates your file (you're now writing into an empty file)

Comment: And remember to put in a newline character ``'\n'`` after the last string.